# How do I change the color for directories with ls in the console?

Tags: colors, console, ls

On my console the color for directories is such a blue, that it is hard to read on a dark background.

How can I change the color definitions for `ls`?

Comment: Use [LSCOLORS Generator](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/); set and export `LSCOLORS` in your shell's `rc`.

Comment: Related question: [How do I remove background colours for directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64590378/183120)

Answer (score 386, accepted):

To change your directory colors, open up your `~/.bashrc` file with your editor

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and make the following entry at the end of the file:

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;35:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Some nice color choices (in this case `0;35` it is purple) are:

```
Blue = 34
Green = 32
Light Green = 1;32
Cyan = 36
Red = 31
Purple = 35
Brown = 33
Yellow = 1;33
Bold White = 1;37
Light Grey = 0;37
Black = 30
Dark Grey= 1;30
```

The first number is the style (1=bold), followed by a semicolon, and then the actual number of the color, possible styles (effects) are:

```
0   = default colour
1   = bold
4   = underlined
5   = flashing text (disabled on some terminals)
7   = reverse field (exchange foreground and background color)
8   = concealed (invisible)
```

The possible backgrounds:

```
40  = black background
41  = red background
42  = green background
43  = orange background
44  = blue background
45  = purple background
46  = cyan background
47  = grey background
100 = dark grey background
101 = light red background
102 = light green background
103 = yellow background
104 = light blue background
105 = light purple background
106 = turquoise background
107 = white background
```

All possible colors:

```
30  = black
31  = red
32  = green
33  = orange
34  = blue
35  = purple
36  = cyan
37  = grey
90  = dark grey
91  = light red
92  = light green
93  = yellow
94  = light blue
95  = light purple
96  = turquoise
97  = white
```

These can even be combined, so that a parameter like:

```
di=1;4;31;42
```

in your LS_COLORS variable would make directories appear in bold underlined red text with a green background!

To test all these colors and styles in your terminal, you can use one of:

```
for i in 00{2..8} {0{3,4,9},10}{0..7}
do echo -e "$i \e[0;${i}mSubdermatoglyphic text\e[00m  \e[1;${i}mSubdermatoglyphic text\e[00m"
done

for i in 00{2..8} {0{3,4,9},10}{0..7}
do for j in 0 1
   do echo -e "$j;$i \e[$j;${i}mSubdermatoglyphic text\e[00m"
   done
done
```

You can also change other kinds of files when using the ls command by defining each kind with:

```
bd = (BLOCK, BLK)   Block device (buffered) special file
cd = (CHAR, CHR)    Character device (unbuffered) special file
di = (DIR)  Directory
do = (DOOR) [Door][1]
ex = (EXEC) Executable file (ie. has 'x' set in permissions)
fi = (FILE) Normal file
ln = (SYMLINK, LINK, LNK)   Symbolic link. If you set this to ‘target’ instead of a numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.
mi = (MISSING)  Non-existent file pointed to by a symbolic link (visible when you type ls -l)
no = (NORMAL, NORM) Normal (non-filename) text. Global default, although everything should be something
or = (ORPHAN)   Symbolic link pointing to an orphaned non-existent file
ow = (OTHER_WRITABLE)   Directory that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
pi = (FIFO, PIPE)   Named pipe (fifo file)
sg = (SETGID)   File that is setgid (g+s)
so = (SOCK) Socket file
st = (STICKY)   Directory with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
su = (SETUID)   File that is setuid (u+s)
tw = (STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE)    Directory that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
*.extension =   Every file using this extension e.g. *.rpm = files with the ending .rpm
```

A more complete list is available at [Bigsoft - Configuring LS_COLORS](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors).

On some distributions, you might also want to change the background color for `ow` "(`OTHER_WRITABLE`) whose default is non-readable" for example to non-bold blue text on green background.

You could use for instance `LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:di=1;33"` at the end of your `.bashrc` file, to get a nice readable bold orange text on black background.

After you alter your .bashrc file, to put the changes in effect you will have to restart your shell or run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Note: You can combine more commands with a **colon**, for example

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;33:ln=36' ; export LS_COLORS; ls
```

*Source:*

- [COLORS Lscolors - Linux StepByStep](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html)
- [Geek Gumbo - Changing the Directory Color in Bash](https://web.archive.org/web/20140807232939/http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/11/04/changing-the-directory-color-in-the-bash-shell/)

Comment: This works well, thanks.  I personally found it better to set `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;44:' ; export LS_COLORS` which shows the directories in bold white over blue background.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It looks like there is another config file somewhere that overwrites `.bashrc` - some colors work, others look differently. Folders are green for instance instead of blue, but files look correctly. What could it be?

Comment: check if you are using bash or sh, and also check your .profile file in your home directory. and global `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put this thorough guide together! This helped me a great deal!

Comment: `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;44:' ; export LS_COLORS` not work on Ubuntu 14.04 zsh.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Cygwin.

Comment: You probably want to modify other writable and sticky other writable dirs.   Try something more like `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'tw=01;35:ow=01;35:' ; export LS_COLORS`

Comment: that worked for ls, but how do i change the color of the dir I am in, before the # in the cmd prompt?

Comment: @gaia: the part before the `#` in the commandline is called "Prompt". You'll find lots of instructions how to change that too

Comment: Thank you for your inspiring answer rubo77. One example for Ubuntu 16.04 alias la='ls -la --color'
alias sula='sudo ls -la --color'
LS_COLORS='di=96;1:fi=0:ln=32;1;4:pi=0:so=0:bd=0:cd=0:or=0:mi=0:ex=31:*.rpm=0'
export LS_COLORS

Comment: @Gaia uncomment the line that says `force_color_prompt=yes`. Then look for a block a little below that, that says `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;32m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '`. Have a read through https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/ I just changed the number for the dark blue (34)  every time I saw it.

Comment: if you want to apply changes made use `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: It works also for `tree` command.

Comment: I use ZSH and `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;35:' ; export LS_COLORS` seems like did not take any affect

Comment: seems like `LS_COLORS` does not considered by ZSH on my end

Comment: For BSD `ls` (e.g. OS X default), note it uses `LSCOLORS` instead of `LS_COLORS`, see e.g. [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484982/what-is-the-difference-between-standard-syntax-and-bsd-syntax) for more info. (Sorry, quite off-topic for Ask Ubuntu but might help someone searching this)

Comment: This is an amzingly useufl post - thank you! 
I can't seem to get the *.extension working? For example: ```LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;36:ex=1,31:ln=1,93:*.vcf=1,33' ; export LS_COLORS; ls``` .vcf files are still coloured the same as others

Comment: Marvellous. The entusiasm! Glad I got to read this.=)

Comment: Note that these numbers for colors and styles correspond with escape sequences to change colors on the command-line. So, you can do lots of other stuff, too, like make text italic (with 3), do 256 colors with 38;5;# (where number is a number; change it to change the color), make colors fainter with 2, strikethrough with 9, and other stuff.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean by escape sequences: e.g. `printf "\e[3;32mHello world\e[0m\n"`.

Comment: To change archive colors, you have to do it manually for each extension (that's what the defaults do if you look at `echo $LS_COLORS`; if you just want them the same as other stuff, don't include the `$LS_COLORS:` part in the command where you set the colors. Is there a way to make non-executable directories a different color than executable ones?

Answer (score 56):

Very simple.
Add these three lines to ~/.bashrc

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

If you want to apply the changes in a running bash session, run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me but I need to run `source ~/.bashrc` every time I log in. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Miguel : what do you get when you type `echo $SHELL` from the cmd prompt? I bet it is NOT `/bin/bash`. You can find your active `.profile` or `.login` and add `source $HOME/.bashrc` at the end. Good luck.

Comment: `zsh: command not found: dircolors
`

Comment: Doesn't this just add the colors. The OP was asking to change them.

Answer (score 12):

Further to Hegazi's answer, you can actually control the directory colour, and a lot of other colours using the dircolors command. You can create a configuration file which is well documented.

You can create a .dircolor file in your home directory as follows:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

Then in your ~/.bashrc file add the lines

```
eval "`dircolors -b ~/.dircolors`"
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

This will create a $LS_COLORS variable for bash. The -c flag will set if for csh. It also flags the ls command to display in colour.

Edit the value of the DIR attribute as above in the ~/.dircolor file colour to change the colour of the directory (or any of the other included file types for other colours).
You can also change the colours of specific files, or define your own.

Comment: Are there any examples of the file format ? Or is it the same as what is outputted when doing dircolors --print-database ?

Comment: The -p flag is a shortcut for --print-database, which is then piped into a text file.

Answer (score 8):

I don't like removing all colors because they are still useful. I prefer to keep current defaults and just remove the green background on directories. For this effect I just add one line to the end of my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ow=1;34:'
```

Answer (score 7):

[LS_COLORS](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS)

This is a collection of extension:color mappings, suitable to use as your LS COLORS environment variable.

Comment: interesting but I can't make this work in ksh.

Comment: The LS_COLORS link was what helped me

Answer (score 2):

The `--color=auto` option doesn't work for me using iTerm2 on my Mac. The `-G` option works though. I put the following alias in my `~/.profile` and now directories are colored and have a trailing `/` appended:

```
alias ls='ls -F -G'
```

Comment: It's because it's BSD utils and not coreutils :)

Comment: Well, this is askubuntu, not "askmac"!

Comment: The `-G` serves to colorize but it uses precisely the unreadable dark blue that's in the OP ;) . Now need to research how to specify the colors in BSD

Answer (score 2):

For the instant solution, `--color=auto` may make no difference.  The option you want is `--color=never`.  Though piping the output through `cat` (or `more`) would also remove the colouring, and is quicker to type:

```
ls -al | cat
```

(I don't know who's idea of a joke it was to make light blue against light green the default.)

Answer (score 1):

[Vivid](https://github.com/sharkdp/vivid) makes the process of changing `ls`'s colors nice and easy.

Install with:

```
wget "https://github.com/sharkdp/vivid/releases/download/v0.7.0/vivid_0.7.0_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i vivid_0.7.0_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution you can put in your init config for dark shells (Molokai, generated with https://github.com/sharkdp/vivid):

```
export LS_COLORS="bd=0;38;2;102;217;239;48;2;51;51;51:rs=0:mi=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;255;74;68:do=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;249;38;114:di=0;38;2;102;217;239:ln=0;38;2;249;38;114:ow=0:fi=0:ca=0:no=0:pi=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;102;217;239:st=0:so=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;249;38;114:sg=0:su=0:ex=1;38;2;249;38;114:cd=0;38;2;249;38;114;48;2;51;51;51:or=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;255;74;68:tw=0:mh=0:*~=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.m=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.z=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.d=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.h=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.o=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.p=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.t=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.a=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.r=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.c=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pl=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.la=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.di=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ml=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.md=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.hi=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.jl=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.wv=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.bz=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.cc=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.mn=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.bc=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.hh=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ex=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.rb=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.rs=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.7z=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.td=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ui=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.sh=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.kt=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.lo=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.gv=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.cr=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.py=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.fs=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.so=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.ll=0;38;2;0;255;135:*css=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ps=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.cp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.gz=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.el=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.vb=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pm=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.js=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.go=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.hs=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ts=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.as=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ko=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.xz=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.rm=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.cs=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.nb=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.rtf=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.com=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.tmp=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.bak=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.img=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.dll=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.git=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.exe=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.xls=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.bcf=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.xml=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.lua=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.sxi=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.ics=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.psd=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.php=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.m4v=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.nix=0;38;2;166;226;46:*TODO=1:*.tcl=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.mp4=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.tex=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ttf=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.ppt=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.xlr=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.tif=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.hxx=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.gvy=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pod=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.deb=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.mid=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.clj=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.gif=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.fls=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.ind=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.dpr=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.kts=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.eps=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.png=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.blg=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.vob=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.bin=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.bag=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.pas=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pro=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.txt=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.vim=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.svg=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.ods=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.ipp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.epp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.def=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.awk=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pgm=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.cxx=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ini=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.wav=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.kex=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.rpm=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.mpg=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.tar=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.rar=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.jar=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.pyd=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.xcf=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.tbz=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.bmp=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.zst=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.dot=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.sxw=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.apk=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.ilg=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.wmv=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.odp=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.xmp=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.pid=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.bz2=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.cpp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*hgrc=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.pbm=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.swp=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.fsi=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.htc=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.cgi=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.toc=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.rst=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.ltx=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.csx=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.pkg=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.fnt=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.tml=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.htm=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.aux=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.mov=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.bib=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.ogg=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.mkv=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.sbt=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.bbl=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.tgz=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.asa=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.cfg=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.bsh=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.mir=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.bst=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.mli=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.odt=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.zip=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.erl=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.vcd=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.pdf=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.yml=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.wma=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.avi=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.inl=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.log=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.bat=1;38;2;249;38;114:*.hpp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.otf=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.pyc=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.zsh=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.exs=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.jpg=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.dox=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.tsx=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.c++=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.fon=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.pyo=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.csv=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.mp3=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.ppm=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.doc=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.pps=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.arj=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.iso=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.m4a=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.idx=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.ps1=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.out=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.sql=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.inc=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.sty=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.elm=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.dmg=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.aif=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.h++=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.fsx=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.ico=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.flv=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.swf=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.docx=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.yaml=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.pptx=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.flac=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.rlib=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.purs=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.opus=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.epub=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.json=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.bash=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.hgrc=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.tiff=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.java=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.xlsx=0;38;2;230;219;116:*.less=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.dart=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.webm=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.lock=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.html=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.mpeg=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.psm1=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.conf=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.psd1=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.diff=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.h264=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.make=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.toml=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.lisp=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.fish=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.tbz2=4;38;2;249;38;114:*.orig=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.jpeg=0;38;2;253;151;31:*.mdown=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.cmake=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.swift=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.xhtml=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.dyn_o=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.class=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.cabal=0;38;2;0;255;135:*passwd=0;38;2;166;226;46:*README=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*.toast=4;38;2;249;38;114:*shadow=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.shtml=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.patch=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.scala=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.cache=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.ipynb=0;38;2;0;255;135:*TODO.md=1:*.groovy=0;38;2;0;255;135:*INSTALL=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*.gradle=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.matlab=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.config=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.dyn_hi=0;38;2;122;112;112:*LICENSE=0;38;2;182;182;182:*.flake8=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.ignore=0;38;2;166;226;46:*COPYING=0;38;2;182;182;182:*setup.py=0;38;2;166;226;46:*TODO.txt=1:*Makefile=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.desktop=0;38;2;166;226;46:*Doxyfile=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.gemspec=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.rgignore=0;38;2;166;226;46:*README.md=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*.fdignore=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.markdown=0;38;2;226;209;57:*.cmake.in=0;38;2;166;226;46:*configure=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.kdevelop=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.DS_Store=0;38;2;122;112;112:*COPYRIGHT=0;38;2;182;182;182:*.gitignore=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.scons_opt=0;38;2;122;112;112:*CODEOWNERS=0;38;2;166;226;46:*SConscript=0;38;2;166;226;46:*Dockerfile=0;38;2;166;226;46:*INSTALL.md=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*SConstruct=0;38;2;166;226;46:*README.txt=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*.gitconfig=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.localized=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.gitmodules=0;38;2;166;226;46:*Makefile.am=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.synctex.gz=0;38;2;122;112;112:*INSTALL.txt=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*Makefile.in=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.travis.yml=0;38;2;230;219;116:*MANIFEST.in=0;38;2;166;226;46:*LICENSE-MIT=0;38;2;182;182;182:*appveyor.yml=0;38;2;230;219;116:*configure.ac=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.applescript=0;38;2;0;255;135:*.fdb_latexmk=0;38;2;122;112;112:*CONTRIBUTORS=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*.clang-format=0;38;2;166;226;46:*.gitattributes=0;38;2;166;226;46:*CMakeCache.txt=0;38;2;122;112;112:*CMakeLists.txt=0;38;2;166;226;46:*LICENSE-APACHE=0;38;2;182;182;182:*CONTRIBUTORS.md=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*requirements.txt=0;38;2;166;226;46:*CONTRIBUTORS.txt=0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;230;219;116:*.sconsign.dblite=0;38;2;122;112;112:*package-lock.json=0;38;2;122;112;112:*.CFUserTextEncoding=0;38;2;122;112;112"
```

Answer (score 1):

A lighter blue can be picked in the 256 color palette rather than in the 16 color palette, instead of di:1;34 use:

```
di:38;5;123
```

or on a single line for bash:

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=38;5;123:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

This means color 123 in the 256 color palette.
The 256 color palette can be shown by running the following script:

```
for fgbg in 38 48 ; do # Foreground / Background
  for color in {0..255} ; do # Colors
    # Display the color
    printf "\e[${fgbg};5;%sm  %3s  \e[0m" $color $color
    # Display 6 colors per lines
    if [ $((($color + 1) % 6)) == 4 ] ; then
        echo # New line
    fi
  done
echo # New line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The is my approach for ls command with commonly used options:

add the following lines into a file called ~/.alias

```
alias ll='ls -lhF --color=auto'
alias llt='ls -lht --color=auto'
alias lla='ls -alF --color=auto'
alias la='ls -A --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF --color=auto'
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

add the following lines into ~/.bashrc

```
if [ -f ~/.alias ]; then
    . ~/.alias
fi
```

Comment: you only need to add `--color=auto` to the `ls` alias - the other aliases with inherit the setting

Answer (score 0):

Put below line into ~/.bashrc you are done.

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

To enable color prompt put one line below

```
PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;31m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
echo $LS_COLORS //copy result in clipboard

open ./zshrc
 
LS_COLORS= ' /*paste clipboard*/ '

//Replace all "32" by "97" 

// "x2" = green  "x7" = white 

export LS_COLORS
```