# How can I enable different color for FORTRAN files (or for that matter any other extension files with different colors) when listing files?

Tags: ls, color-management

I want to display different color for different kinds of files. For example, all script files are generally highlighted in green color in bash. Similarly, I want to have a different color for all FORTRAN files etc.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [Ubunttu-WIKI](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/dircolors/). its for trusty and precise but im pretty sure it will work on later versioins aswell.

Comment: The basic method is well described in this closely-related question [How do I change the color for directories with ls in the console?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) - for the specific case of Fortran source files (assuming they are identified by a .f suffix) you could do  something like `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.f=0;35:' ; export LS_COLORS` (replace the color code `0;35` by one of your own choosing).