# Change colors displayed when using Putty session

Tags: ssh

I am using Putty to ssh into my Ubuntu server installation. When i list out folders and files the directories are listed in a very dark blue that I can barely make out...how can I change the default color that is displayed? Is this a function of Ubuntu or something I have to do in Putty (which I looked and didn't see anything really)

Comment: See [How do I change the color for directories with ls in the console?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) - PuTTY should respect `LS_COLORS` at least if you have checked the `Allow terminal to specify ANSI colours' box (under Settings -> Colours)

Answer (score 1):

Run `alias ls` to see if `ls` is aliased to a command which colorizes the output.  If so (and you don't want to change the colors, but just eliminate colorization), run `unalias ls` to remove colorization from the current shell.

To permanently remove the aliasing, find where the alias is set (most likely in `~/.bashrc`) and comment out or delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i think i want to keep the colored output but just modify how directories are displayed