# Turning off text highlighting

Tags: bash

Some directories are highlighted green in my ll list so that it becomes unreadable. How can I switch that off?

[image]

I tried to upload a screenshot, but it wont show it... I hope my question is still clear

So, I tried to change it following 
[How do I change the color for directories with ls in the console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console)

I went through all the types in the list

```
di = directory
fi = file
ln = symbolic link
pi = fifo file
so = socket file
bd = block (buffered) special file
cd = character (unbuffered) special file
or = symbolic link pointing to a non-existent file (orphan)
mi = non-existent file pointed to by a symbolic link (visible when you type    ls -l)
ex = file which is executable (ie. has 'x' set in permissions).
*.rpm = files with the ending .rpm
```

but that type did not change. it actually is a directory. for some reasons there seem to be two styles for directories. one is just dark blue no background, the other one has the green background that makes it unreadable. the di option only changes the directories that are dark blue and readable.
Ideally I would avoid having a solution that removes all highlighting like ll --color=none. I would prefer to just get rid of that background
The unreadable directories have the signature drwxrwxrwx, while the readable ones have drwxr-xr-x

Comment: The one you want is probably `ow` (other-writable), I'll update the other post once I get a reference

Comment: ah, thanks. ow is indeed the type of those directories. I could change it now with LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ow=1;33' ; export LS_COLORS

Comment: As an aside, I hope you have a good reason for all those 777 permissions ;)

Answer (score 2):

`ll` is an alias defined in `~/.bashrc` along with other alias's that use color:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Add a "redalert" alias to pop-up on GUI desktop screens.  Use like so:
#   redalert "Weather update: It's raining Red States"
alias redalert='notify-send --urgency=critical -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

The last **Alias**: ***redalert*** I added manually and is not in normal Ubuntu distributions.

What you can do if you want no colors is use:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/dircolors
```

However in your case you might be looking at a windows partition, ie:

[image: windows directory]

In which case you can simply use `\ls -alF` for no colors:

[image: ls no colors]

Comment: when I use `\ls -laF` it works but I get `ls: cannot read symbolic link 'My Music': Permission denied`.  Is there another way?