# Listing files of identical type with ls command can produce files with different colors

Tags: command-line, ls

Can someone please explain to me why when listing certain files with the same extension, eg .jpg files, why they are sometimes listed green, as well as shown in pink. These are all image files. It doesn't make sense.

[image: Listing of image files]

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/17299/295286

Answer (score 2):

The file `WhiterShadePale1.jpg` has execute permissions. That's all there is to it. The executable colour overrides the *.jpg colour.

Comment: I know it's shown as an executable file, but why? It isn't a program. It's just an image file like the others that are shown.

Comment: It's shown as an excecutable because it IS an executable :) The reason for that could be many, but it's obviously a wrong executeable flag set on this particular file. By the way ls with colors will often help to identify permissions issues like this.

Comment: @PaulBenson It has its execute permissions. If you run `ls -l WhiterShadePale1.jpg`, you will probably see the first column is `-rwxrwxr-x`, where the x's indicate execute permissions. For more info, see [How do file permissions work?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83/301745)

Comment: @PaulBenson If it wasn't clear, the file doesn't need to have execute permissions, but it's not a problem.

Comment: Thnx. It's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The colors are controlled by the environment variable `LS_COLORS`.

The `ls` man page states:

> ```
> LS_COLORS       The value of this variable describes what color to use
>                 for which attribute when colors are enabled with
>                 CLICOLOR.  This string is a concatenation of pairs of the
>                 format fb, where f is the foreground color and b is the
>                 background color.
>
>                 The color designators are as follows:
>
>                       a     black
>                       b     red
>                       c     green
>                       d     brown
>                       e     blue
>                       f     magenta
>                       g     cyan
>                       h     light grey
>                       A     bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
>                       B     bold red
>                       C     bold green
>                       D     bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
>                       E     bold blue
>                       F     bold magenta
>                       G     bold cyan
>                       H     bold light grey; looks like bright white
>                       x     default foreground or background
>
>                 Note that the above are standard ANSI colors.  The actual
>                 display may differ depending on the color capabilities of
>                 the terminal in use.
>
>                 The order of the attributes are as follows:
>
>                       1.   directory
>                       2.   symbolic link
>                       3.   socket
>                       4.   pipe
>                       5.   executable
>                       6.   block special
>                       7.   character special
>                       8.   executable with setuid bit set
>                       9.   executable with setgid bit set
>                       10.  directory writable to others, with sticky bit
>                       11.  directory writable to others, without sticky
>                            bit
>
>                 The default is "exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", i.e. blue fore-
>                 ground and default background for regular directories,
>                 black foreground and red background for setuid executa-
>                 bles, etc.
> ```

Comment: I think you got that from a BSD manpage, cause on Ubuntu, `LSCOLORS` is not used. Instead it's `LS_COLORS`, which has a totally different structure.

Comment: You're right.  Let me update.  Seems like the Ubuntu man page doesn't go into as much detail about how it works as the BSD but since this is from GNU coreutils it shouldn't matter.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console goes into more details.  There is another command dircolors(1) - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dircolors.1.html which can be used to set colors.

Comment: Your update didn't fix the problem. It's not just that the variable has a different name, it's that it has a totally different internal structure: it's a colon-delimited list of type=color pairs.