# Green highlights on some directories on running ls command

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, ls

On running the ls command to under any directory, I find that some directories (and this happens with directories only) have an annoying green highlight around them for no apparent reason.

Would appreciate help to make this stop.

EDIT: This problem has cropped up suddenly. Would like to keep ls command color coding in general, but avoid these seemingly arbitrary directory highlights.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Putting a \ in front of ls will have it drop colors ;-) see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console on how to edit the colors for ls

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the tips. I don't have a problem with the color coding scheme, but here ls chooses to highlight only a few directories selectively

Comment: Duplicate question at U&L SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94498/256762

Comment: @pomsky I realise that the question is a duplicate, but the one over on unix does not seem to answer how to change the `dircolors` settings

Comment: perhaps use an alternative terminal like konsole (which also saves sessions)