# What are the default LS_COLORS and DIR_COLORS values in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, colors, default

I'd like to have Ubuntu style on my system's terminal, which is not Ubuntu. Could someone be so kind to post the values of unmodified original `$LS_COLORS` and `$DIR_COLORS` here from his/her Ubuntu system? I.e. the output of `echo $LS_COLORS` and `echo $DIR_COLORS`.

Also if there is something else which affects the coloring of the `ls` and `dir` outputs, I'd like to know that too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my `echo $LS_COLORS` output:

```
rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

And here are the contents of the above (default) `$LS_COLORS` variable in a one-column list form:

```
rs=0
di=01;34
ln=01;36
mh=00
pi=40;33
so=01;35
do=01;35
bd=40;33;01
cd=40;33;01
or=40;31;01
mi=00
su=37;41
sg=30;43
ca=30;41
tw=30;42
ow=34;42
st=37;44
ex=01;32
*.tar=01;31
*.tgz=01;31
*.arc=01;31
*.arj=01;31
*.taz=01;31
*.lha=01;31
*.lz4=01;31
*.lzh=01;31
*.lzma=01;31
*.tlz=01;31
*.txz=01;31
*.tzo=01;31
*.t7z=01;31
*.zip=01;31
*.z=01;31
*.dz=01;31
*.gz=01;31
*.lrz=01;31
*.lz=01;31
*.lzo=01;31
*.xz=01;31
*.zst=01;31
*.tzst=01;31
*.bz2=01;31
*.bz=01;31
*.tbz=01;31
*.tbz2=01;31
*.tz=01;31
*.deb=01;31
*.rpm=01;31
*.jar=01;31
*.war=01;31
*.ear=01;31
*.sar=01;31
*.rar=01;31
*.alz=01;31
*.ace=01;31
*.zoo=01;31
*.cpio=01;31
*.7z=01;31
*.rz=01;31
*.cab=01;31
*.wim=01;31
*.swm=01;31
*.dwm=01;31
*.esd=01;31
*.jpg=01;35
*.jpeg=01;35
*.mjpg=01;35
*.mjpeg=01;35
*.gif=01;35
*.bmp=01;35
*.pbm=01;35
*.pgm=01;35
*.ppm=01;35
*.tga=01;35
*.xbm=01;35
*.xpm=01;35
*.tif=01;35
*.tiff=01;35
*.png=01;35
*.svg=01;35
*.svgz=01;35
*.mng=01;35
*.pcx=01;35
*.mov=01;35
*.mpg=01;35
*.mpeg=01;35
*.m2v=01;35
*.mkv=01;35
*.webm=01;35
*.ogm=01;35
*.mp4=01;35
*.m4v=01;35
*.mp4v=01;35
*.vob=01;35
*.qt=01;35
*.nuv=01;35
*.wmv=01;35
*.asf=01;35
*.rm=01;35
*.rmvb=01;35
*.flc=01;35
*.avi=01;35
*.fli=01;35
*.flv=01;35
*.gl=01;35
*.dl=01;35
*.xcf=01;35
*.xwd=01;35
*.yuv=01;35
*.cgm=01;35
*.emf=01;35
*.ogv=01;35
*.ogx=01;35
*.aac=00;36
*.au=00;36
*.flac=00;36
*.m4a=00;36
*.mid=00;36
*.midi=00;36
*.mka=00;36
*.mp3=00;36
*.mpc=00;36
*.ogg=00;36
*.ra=00;36
*.wav=00;36
*.oga=00;36
*.opus=00;36
*.spx=00;36
*.xspf=00;36
```

In my installation of Ubuntu 20.04 I don't have a `$DIR_COLORS` variable.

Also have a look at these related questions:

- [How do I change the color for directories with ls in the console?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console)
- [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls)

Comment: Did they change directory colors to blue from light blue? I set this as my ls_colors value, but changed di=01;34 to di=01;92 as it must have been 9 years ago

Comment: From the links in my answer (which are about 10 years old) it seems that the colors haven't changed. In most answers I can see `01;34` for the directories. Maybe the difference you see is due to a terminal setting, e.g. a setting to show bold text in bright colors, or your terminal's theme.

Answer (score 0):

The LS_COLORS variable is likely set using the GNU dircolors command, from : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544071/40271

The [dircolors man page](https://alvinalexander.com/unix/man/man5/dir_colors.5.shtml) explains how to edit the dircolors database.