# Ubuntu terminal ls lists folders but not files

Tags: command-line, files, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ls

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu so I'm thinking I might've installed it incorrectly or something since this never happened on my old laptop, but here's what's happening:

I'm using the ubuntu terminal from the microsoft store, and all I've done to it so far is 'sudo apt update' and the command to install gcc.

When accessing windows directories, my Ubuntu terminal can only find directories but not files. So when I use ls the folders will be listed, but not any of the files.

[image: screenshot of ls command]

However, I can still create/modify/delete files from the terminal, even though I can't see them.

So yeah, I'm not sure if this error is just because I haven't set it up properly or something, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling already. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looks like a problem with the colour-scheme used in the terminal and you just can't see the files but they are displayed black on black, so  you can't see them.

Comment: Oh, that's so strange haha. How would I change the colour for specific text? In 'properties' I can only see an option to change the colour of the text already in silver.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you use Windows Subsystem for Linux, I don't have any experience with that, so I can't help you much. Hopefully someone else of our gurus joins in and is able to help you.

Comment: Yeah, I do. No worries though, thank you so much!

Comment: See [the answers to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console). Maybe you can try something similar in WSL.

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/questions/1365258/how-to-change-the-dark-blue-in-wsl-to-something-brighter

Comment: Sure thing, thank you! I'll go have a look

Comment: Fixed it, thanks guys! None of the linux code for changing text was working and the fix was a little strange so leaving here for anybody else who comes across this issue. In 'Properties' after right clicking the top of the window, then in 'Colors', if you change the colour in the 6th box from the right the black text's colour will change too, meaning you can now see it as long as your background colour isn't set to that box.

Comment: I am glad you fixed the problem. It will be great if you click on the button below "Answer your own question" and write the solution that worked for you. Then after the required wait time accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the grey check box and turn it green. This will help others.