# Changing LS_COLORS in Ubuntu 22.04 works in terminal but not permanently in .bashrc

Tags: server, bash, 22.04, environment-variables, ls

I am learning linux thoroughly, I have downloaded my first VM with vmware-fusion on my `mac m1`.

I have tried many times to update the `.bashrc` file but the one thing that is not changing for some reason is the directory color.

I have updated the question.

I can't understand who decided to keep that dark blue.

Since i am using vmware-fusion on my Mac M1, I can't copy and paste the code, but I can find a way to get the code, here are the screenshots

[image: Changing LS Colors in .bashrc]

[image: Updating the .bashrc file]

[image: I see the same barely readable blue colours]

Then when I change the colour from the terminal it works with the ls command:

[image]

But if I do a source of the .bashrc file again it doesn't work:

[image: Changes not staying permanent]

Is this because i am using a virtual machine on mac m1 ?
I must be missing something else in the config file.

I have set the force color prompt to true
[image: Force color prompt set to true]

When I do an echo of the LS, I do see the new colors added at the end but they are not taking effect:

[image: Changes not taking effect]

I did this in a new VM and it worked:

Any advice would be so appreciated

Comment: AFAIK `01:35` should be `01;35` and `export $LS_COLORS` should be `export LS_COLORS` (although the latter should not be necessary, since `LS_COLORS` should have already been exported by `eval "$(dircolors -b)"`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this, I made the changes and updated the question but no difference, anything else I could do ? I can't find any info where I can create a dircolors file but since its just that one barely readable blue I want to change, I can't understand why it is so hard

Comment: You can check the basic functionality by setting the variable's value on the command line - does `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=01;35:' ls` work for example?

Comment: No it didn't work. I tried that as well, the only difference is the new value was appended to the end of the variable, I have edited the question

Comment: Maybe there is some option i need to change in the .bashrc file

Comment: Please make sure you are running `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=01;35:' ls` **not** `echo LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=01;35:' ls`

Comment: Hey, thanks I tried that and it works when I don't do the echo, How could I get this to work in the .bashrc ?

Comment: When I do source .bashrc it goes back to the blue

Comment: Does your .bashrc contain a section that contains something like `eval "$(dircolors -b)"`? if so, make sure that any changes you make to the `LS_COLORS` variable are **after** that - else they will be overwritten

Comment: No there is no such line of code & The LS_COLORS is the last line in the file

Comment: Perhaps this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) will help you.  Yes, you're not the only one annoyed by that dark blue -- really hard to see on a black background.  I suggest you use the answer by "smilingfrog", which asks you use run the `dircolors -p` command to generate a separate file.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking of answering or closing this question. I deleted that VM and created a new one and now it seems to be working, so I guess it might be some kind of bug lower down or to do with cache, that I have not been able to track ? I would love to know who/what came up with the idea for that dark blue